# I want texts inside 2 cells start on the same line

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am having a little problem with my table.
On my third row I have 2 cells with texts inside of them , but in one of them the text is longer and in the other one the text is shorter..

Is there any way to make the texts start on the same line without adding/deleting text ?

```
<div class="section2 center">
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Our services</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Isolation and loneliness</th>
        <th>Family conflict or separation</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Human beings are naturally social animals. When we find 
         ourselves becoming isolated, we should take that as a warning sign 
         that we are turned against ourselves in some basic way. If not 
         already there, we are on a path toward feeling bad, lonely, 
         introverted or even depressed. Read more...</td>
        <td>Parental separation often initially leads to an increase in 
         parental conflict and anger, although for some families the level 
         of conflict reduces when parents do not see each other regularly. 
         Read more...</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="height:5px"></tr>


    <tr>
        <th>Death of loss</th>
        <th>Child psychological program</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>     There are many kinds of loss and each has its own kind of 
        grief. People lose loved ones like spouses, partners, children, 
        family members, and friends. Even pet losses can cause grief. job or 
        property loss can be painful. Read more...</td>
        <td>The basic premise of the program is that children who avoid 
        interactions with their peers or have difficulties in these 
        interactions do so because of a skill deficit or excessive anxiety. 
        Read more...</td>
    </tr>
</div>

    ---CSS---

.section2 table {
    align:center;
    margin-top:80px;
}

.section2 table tr:first-child>th {
   font-size:25px;
}

.section2 table tr:nth-child(3) {
   height:auto;
}


.section2 table tr:nth-child(3) td {
   width:200px;
   background-color:blue;
   padding:20px;
   text-align:center;
}

.section2 table tr:nth-child(6) td {
   padding:20px;
   text-align:center;
   background-color:red;
}
```

[image: I attached this picture to see how it looks on my laptop.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add

```
.section2 table tr td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

to your code.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/32n2zjky/

Comment: you can upvote and accept this answer if it helps you @clauu

Comment: Glad I could help you. And don't forget to also upvote the answer of @Zuber aswell when doing so. He answered the question just about a little moment afterwards. On top of that, you can mark any of the two answers as correct by clicking on the checkmark icon next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `vertical-align: top` to `td` in your `head` tag like this

```
<style>
  td {
    vertical-align: top;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to add

```
.section2 table tr {
     vertical-align: top;
}
```

And by the way, instead `align:center` should by `text-align:center`

```css
.section2 table {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:80px;
}

.section2 table tr {
     vertical-align: top;
}

.section2 table tr:first-child>th {
   font-size:25px;
}

.section2 table tr:nth-child(3) {
   height:auto;
}


.section2 table tr:nth-child(3) td {
   width:200px;
   background-color:blue;
   padding:20px;
   text-align:center;
}

.section2 table tr:nth-child(6) td {
   padding:20px;
   text-align:center;
   background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="section2 center">
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Our services</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Isolation and loneliness</th>
        <th>Family conflict or separation</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Human beings are naturally social animals. When we find 
         ourselves becoming isolated, we should take that as a warning sign 
         that we are turned against ourselves in some basic way. If not 
         already there, we are on a path toward feeling bad, lonely, 
         introverted or even depressed. Read more...</td>
        <td>Parental separation often initially leads to an increase in 
         parental conflict and anger, although for some families the level 
         of conflict reduces when parents do not see each other regularly. 
         Read more...</td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="height:5px"></tr>


    <tr>
        <th>Death of loss</th>
        <th>Child psychological program</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>     There are many kinds of loss and each has its own kind of 
        grief. People lose loved ones like spouses, partners, children, 
        family members, and friends. Even pet losses can cause grief. job or 
        property loss can be painful. Read more...</td>
        <td>The basic premise of the program is that children who avoid 
        interactions with their peers or have difficulties in these 
        interactions do so because of a skill deficit or excessive anxiety. 
        Read more...</td>
    </tr>
</div>
```